# Why a function checking if a string is empty always returns true?

Tags: php, string, validation

I have a function isNotEmpty which returns true if the string is not empty and false if the string is empty. I've found out that it is not working if I pass an empty string through it.

```
function isNotEmpty($input) 
{
    $strTemp = $input;
    $strTemp = trim($strTemp);

    if(strTemp != '') //Also tried this "if(strlen($strTemp) > 0)"
    {
         return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The validation of the string using isNotEmpty is done:

```
if(isNotEmpty($userinput['phoneNumber']))
{
    //validate the phone number
}
else
{
    echo "Phone number not entered<br/>";
}
```

If the string is empty the else doesn't execute, I don't understand why, can someone please shed some light on this please.

Comment: Just a suggestion: it is generally a bad practice to use functions with negated names. It is more readable to have function isEmpty($input), otherwise you might call it like this: if (!isNotEmpty($x)) ... On the other hand, isNotEmpty() and (!isEmpty()) is not that different. YMMV.

Comment: To have the same function without a negated name, perhaps something like hasContent().

Comment: *!thatDifferent* @johndodo

Comment: This is DEFINITELY an **Off-topic: Typo** question.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

Simple problem actually. Change:

```
if (strTemp != '')
```

to

```
if ($strTemp != '')
```

Arguably you may also want to change it to:

```
if ($strTemp !== '')
```

since `!= ''` will return true if you pass is numeric 0 and a few other cases due to [PHP's automatic type conversion](http://sldn.softlayer.com/01/2009/php-type-conversions-for-comparison/).

You **should not** use the built-in [empty()](http://www.php.net/empty) function for this; see comments and the [PHP type comparison tables](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: Arguably, change the if into: return $strTemp !== '';

Comment: Yes, that's it, I don't know how I missed on the $ sign. Also tested passing value 0 and it works. Thanks for your response.

Comment: you don't want to use empty(). Consider a string of spaces: $x = "  "; var_dump(!empty($x)); /* (TRUE) */ var_dump(isNotEmpty($x)); /* (FALSE) */

Comment: The OP is trimming the string. In this case its appropriate.

Comment: @cletus: then consider a string $s='0'. If you call empty($s) it will evaluate to true (not intuitive imho, but it is so).

Comment: Don't use empty()! empty() will return true for values such as '0'. See php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: I've yet to understand why `if( $str !== '' )` is not the definitive answer for this question... I'd genuinely like to know if there's any reason for not using this always, or if there is a valid reason to jump through hoops not to use it.

Comment: i think the better approach is simply checking the length of the string i.e. `strlen($data)`

Answer (score 30):

I always use a regular expression for checking for an empty string, dating back to CGI/Perl days, and also with Javascript, so why not with PHP as well, e.g. (albeit untested)

```
return preg_match('/\S/', $input);
```

Where `\S` represents any non-whitespace character

Comment: This is the only solution here that doesn't assume zero is the same as an empty string!

Comment: Cool solution. As a side note, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4544642/5411817 mentions: *By default `.` doesn't match new lines - `[\s\S]` is a hack around that problem.
This is common in JavaScript, but in PHP you can use the `/s` flag to to make the dot match all characters.* And https://stackoverflow.com/a/4544646/5411817 mentions: *`(?s)` turns on the `s` mode and `(?-s)` turns if off. Once turned off any following `.` will not match a newline.* if you want to turn the switch on/off inline (embedded inside the regex) instead of as a regex flag.

Answer (score 24):

In your `if` clause in the function, you're referring to a variable `strTemp` that doesn't exist. `$strTemp` does exist, though.

But PHP already has an `empty()` function available; why make your own?

```
if (empty($str))
    /* String is empty */
else
    /* Not empty */
```

From php.net:

> Return Values
>
> Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty
>   and non-zero value.
>
> The following things are considered to
>   be empty:
>
> ```
> * "" (an empty string)
> * 0 (0 as an integer)
> * "0" (0 as a string)
> * NULL
> * FALSE
> * array() (an empty array)
> * var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
> ```

http://www.php.net/empty

Comment: Not all implementations would want "0" to be evaluated as empty. And if he wanted that, couldn't he just as well use the if($x) comparison i.e. If(!trim($str))?

Comment: Note that doing $tmpStr != '' will also return true of $tmpStr holds 0 or false or another empty/false value.

Comment: Your version won't actually work: empty works on variables, not on expressions.

Answer (score 22):

PHP have a built in function called `empty()`
the test is done by typing 
`if(empty($string)){...}`
Reference php.net : [php empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: the empty reference is already at the end of the accepted answer from cletus. See as well that this question and answer thread is from april 2009. Anyway thanks for your input. I'm giving you a +1 for a first answer.

Comment: Don't use empty()! empty() will return true for values such as '0'. See http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: @ScottDavidTesler If the string is "0" will it return true? Or only if it is the integer 0?

Comment: @TomasZubiri Yes, a string containing "0" will return true.

Comment: PLEASE, no one else upvote this WRONG answer - read the above comments!

Comment: This is PHP, there's somehow no distinction between the number `0` and the string `"0"`. Lol.

Answer (score 13):

PHP evaluates an empty string to false, so you can simply use:

```
if (trim($userinput['phoneNumber'])) {
  // validate the phone number
} else {
  echo "Phone number not entered<br/>";
}
```

Comment: This works fine until you pas 0. Otherwise the idea is great, I'll us it it on some other places. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 10):

Just use  strlen() function

```
if (strlen($s)) {
   // not empty
}
```

Comment: it depends on how PHP implements strlen() function.  For example, in Delphi, the string actually has stored its length minus 4 byte offset, so checking its length is trivial.

Comment: Not type save. Before `Php 5.3` the function will return `5` if `$s` is of type `array`. `Php > 5.3` will rise an exception. I recommend using `is_string($s) && str_len($s) > 0`. `>0` just for reading purposes.

Answer (score 7):

I just write my own function, [is_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) for type checking and [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to check the length.

```
function emptyStr($str) {
    return is_string($str) && strlen($str) === 0;
}

print emptyStr('') ? "empty" : "not empty";
// empty
```

[Here's a small test repl.it](https://repl.it/JzKC)

EDIT: You can also use the [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to test if the string is also blank.

```
is_string($str) && strlen(trim($str)) === 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to test for an empty field in PHP and used

```
ctype_space($tempVariable)
```

which worked well for me.

Comment: This is a correct answer to a different question.  This answer DOES NOT check if a string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the short method to check whether the string is empty or not.

```
$input; //Assuming to be the string


if(strlen($input)==0){
return false;//if the string is empty
}
else{
return true; //if the string is not empty
}
```

Comment: Checking the `strlen()` was recommended in 2014 on this page.  Your answer adds no new value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast to bool, dont forget to handle zero.

```
function isEmpty(string $string): bool {
    if($string === '0') {
        return false;
    }
    return !(bool)$string;
}

var_dump(isEmpty('')); // bool(true)
var_dump(isEmpty('foo')); // bool(false)
var_dump(isEmpty('0')); // bool(false)
```

Comment: `(bool)$str` is the same as doing `!empty($str)`, and has the same problem with `'0'`. Read [PHP Booleans](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), the section "Converting to boolean".  Also, you got it backwards - should be `!(bool)$string'`. Or your function should be named "isNotEmpty". Regardless, you are stuck with incorrect handling of '0'.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve For the `0` problem just handle that before returning the casted string. And thanks a lot, i forgot the negation `!` (negated function names are bad practice). Edited my post.

Answer (score -1):

I know this thread been pretty old but I just wanted to share one of my function. This function below can check for empty strings, string with maximum lengths, minimum lengths, or exact length. If you want to check for empty strings, just put $min_len and $max_len as 0.

```
function chk_str( $input, $min_len = null, $max_len = null ){

    if ( !is_int($min_len) && $min_len !== null ) throw new Exception('chk_str(): $min_len must be an integer or a null value.');
    if ( !is_int($max_len) && $max_len !== null ) throw new Exception('chk_str(): $max_len must be an integer or a null value.'); 

    if ( $min_len !== null && $max_len !== null ){
         if ( $min_len > $max_len ) throw new Exception('chk_str(): $min_len can\'t be larger than $max_len.');
    }

    if ( !is_string( $input ) ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $output = true;
    }

    if ( $min_len !== null ){
        if ( strlen($input) < $min_len ) $output = false;
    }

    if ( $max_len !== null ){
        if ( strlen($input) > $max_len ) $output = false;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if you have a field namely serial_number and want to check empty then

```
$serial_number = trim($_POST[serial_number]);
$q="select * from product where user_id='$_SESSION[id]'";
$rs=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
if(empty($_POST['irons'])){
$irons=$row['product1'];
}
```

in this way you can chek all the fileds in the loop with another empty function

Comment: `empty()` was already recommended on this page back in 2009.

Answer (score -2):

this is the short and effective solution, exactly what you're looking for :

```
return $input > null ? 'not empty' : 'empty' ;
```

Comment: I haven't tested whether this works, but if it does, it would be by converting `null` to empty string for comparison.  In which case, it would be much clearer to say what you mean:  `$input > ''`.  That is, "perform a lexical comparison between the input string and an empty string". Or to ignore whitespace at ends: `trim($input) > ''`.

Comment: ... Also need to test what happens when `$input` is `'0'`. Not clear whether php does a `numeric` or `lexical` comparison, when first argument is a numeric string.

Answer (score -3):

You got an answer but in your case you can use

```
return empty($input);
```

or

```
return is_string($input);
```

Comment: this fails for `empty("0")`

Comment: @geekido - downvoting wrong answers is part of StackOverflow - it moves those answers down, and encourages answerers to correct their answer, or remove it. Do you understand what is wrong with your answer? 1. `empty` - this answer has already been given, so saying it again doesn't contribute anything. Worse, as has been discussed in comments, it is wrong - any value equivalent to `0` will be considered "empty". 2. `is_string` is wrong in a different way - an empty string `''` is a string, so will return true in that case - fails to do what question asks.