# What does [\S\s]* mean in regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

What is meant by `[\s\S]*` in regex in PHP? Does `[\s\S]*` actually match every string the same as `.*`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

By default `.` doesn't match new lines - `[\s\S]` is a hack around that problem.
This is common in JavaScript, but in PHP you can use the `/s` flag to to make the dot match all characters.

Comment: When does `.` match new line?

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks, I was just getting to it, just had to confirm that's how it's done in PHP.

Comment: @yoyo - I've changed "Sometimes" to "by default". It doesn't match unless you tell it to match. Just to be clear - there's probably no good reason to use it, unless you want mixed behavior in the same regex, which can also be achieved in better ways (which I see codaddict has already edited into his answer).

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in JavaScript, you can use the `m` modifier for the same effect than `/s` in PHP.

Comment: @PhiLho - `/m` changes the meaning of `^` and `$`, so they also match newlines, it has no effect on `.`. Calling `/s` `singleline` is an historical error which causes confusion with `multiline`, it should be `Dot-Matches-All`.

Comment: @Kobi You are right, so I was indeed mistaken... :-) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions for example is clear on the `.` and `m` semantics.

Answer (score 28):

The `.` meta character matches any character except a newline. So the pattern `.*` which is used to match anything will not work if you have to match newlines as-well.

```
preg_match('/^.*$/',"hello\nworld"); // returns 0
```

`[\s\S]` which is a character class of white-space characters and non-whitespace characters matches **any** character including a newline so do `[\d\D]`, `[\w\W]`. So your pattern `[\s\S]*` now matches anything.

```
preg_match('/^[\s\S]$/s',"hello\nworld"); // returns 1
```

An alternative to make `.` match anything (including a newline) is to use a `s` modifier.

```
preg_match('/^.*$/s',"hello\nworld"); // returns 1
```

Alternative way of using the `s` modifier is in-lining it as:

```
preg_match('/^(?s).*(?-s)$/',"hello\nworld"); // returns 1
```

`(?s)` turns on the `s` mode and `(?-s)` turns if off. Once turned off any following `.` will not match a newline.

Comment: Does the last bit only modify the behavior of the adjacent `.`? I've not seen that syntax before.

Comment: @BoltClock - you can set or clear flags inline - it works for all dots until you clear it: `(?smi).*abc(?-smi).*aBc`

Answer (score 5):

`[\s\S]` A character set that matches any character including line breaks.

`.` Matches any character except line breaks.