# How to understand the output of the PHP regex matching below?

Tags: php, regex

```
$file = '{include file="{$COMMON_TPL_PATH}common/header_admin.tpl"}
{include file="{$mainPage}"}
{include file="{$COMMON_TPL_PATH}common/footer_admin.tpl"}';
preg_match('/^(\{\})|^(\{\*([\S\s]*?)\*\})|^(<\?(?:php\w+|=|[a-zA-Z]+)?)|^([     ]*[
]+[  ]*)|^(\{strip\})|^(\{\/strip\})|^(\{literal\})|^(\{\s{1,}\/)|^(\{\s{1,})|^(\{\/)|^(\{)|^(([\S\s]*?)(?=([    ]*[
]+[  ]*|\{|<\?)))|^([\S\s]+)/', $file, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Why the output is:

```
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "{"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
  [7]=>
  string(0) ""
  [8]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9]=>
  string(0) ""
  [10]=>
  string(0) ""
  [11]=>
  string(0) ""
  [12]=>
  string(1) "{"
}
```

It seems to me that `^([\S\s]+)` can match the whole string..

Comment: You are right about `[\s\S]`. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544636/what-does-s-s-mean-in-regex-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that group 12 (`^(\{)`) matches successfully, and therefore the regex engine stops. It never even gets to try to match group 16 (`^([\S\s]+)`).

If you put group 16 before group 12, then it will match the entire string. However, since `[\s\S]` matches any character at all (and can be abbreviated to `.` when using the `s` modifier), then none of the other groups will ever match.

All in all, your regex looks quite weird. I wouldn't be surprised if it contained a few bugs aside from the obvious warts like trying to put several spaces into a single character class.

Comment: BTW,what does `(?=` mean in the above regex?

Comment: `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead. It asserts that it is possible to match its contents at the current position without actually adding those characters to the match. So `foo(?=bar)` will match `foo` only if it is followed by `bar`.