# match pattern only at first or at the end of a string with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

**sample codes**:

```
<div>content</div><a href="http://www.example.com">jump link</a>
<div>content</div><a href="http://www.example.com">jump link</a>
<div>content</div><a href="http://www.example.com">jump link</a>
```

I want to replace the first or the end anchor element() of matches in a string.

my regex pattern is:

```
<a.[^>]*>.[^<>]*</a>
```

that would be matches all anchor elements

actually I just want to replace the first match only but I'm really  curious about the possibility to replace at the end of matches.

Thanks

Comment: Some things are not possible with regular expressions. Take a look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: can you provide a clear example of what you would like the result of the regex to be? You want to match what and replace it with what?

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to replace the **first match only**

If you don't use the `g` [global flag](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp), only the first match will be replaced. [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e14uuczw/):

```
var res = str.replace(/<a[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>/, "first");
```

To bind a match to the start of a string, use `^` [start anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

---

> curious about the possibility to replace at the **end of matches**.

If you just want to replace something at the end of a string, use the [end anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`

But to replace the last match of a pattern, put something to eat up before and [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).
Replace with `$1`... where `$1` contains matches of the first [parenthesized subpattern](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64d1654r/1/):

```
var res = str.replace(/([\s\S]*)<a[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>/, "$1last");
```

`([\s\S]*)` [greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) eats up [any character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544636/what-does-s-s-mean-in-regex-in-php) and captures to `$1` until the subsequent pattern is found.

---

*Sidenote*: Regex is not appropriate for parsing arbitrary html. Consider [using a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js).

Comment: awesome !, I realized that I  have mistaken that what I am currently testing on regexpal will be the same when I run the codes on browser. and now the lesson from this case is every programming language has their own way to implement regex. Thanks guy, I appreciate it . now I know there are some flags that can be used in javascript.