# Regex for - or _ at beginning or end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to check if my string has an underscore or hyphen at either the beginning or the end.

```
// pass
sdq
lorem ipsum
abc_def
harry-_potter


// catch
fg_
_asq
_dqw-
-asq-sq
```

Tried out the following but I'm learning regex so I'm not quite sure how to go forward from here:

```
/^[-_]?.*[-_]$/

^        => beginning anchor
[-_]?    => start with either - or _, optionally
.*       => match any number of any character (I believe I could have used ranges here)
[-_]$    => check for - or _ at the end
```

I also know that one possible solution could be to use `|`, which is used for conditions, and what I need is to be able to check that:

> There is either a hypher or underscore at the beginning *or* end of the string.

How can I check this? Can I use something other than `|`?

Comment: `/^[-_]|[-_]$/` is the right solution .

Comment: To match the full string, you may use `^[-_].*|.*[-_]$`.

Comment: `/^[_\-]|[_\-]$/ ` works perfectly, as does @anubhava's

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: the middle of the string doesn't matter, no need to even examine it, and then you also have the infamous `.*` "bug" in js regexp.

Comment: @dandavis Can you link to the reading material regarding the bug you mentioned?

Comment: `/^[-_]|[_-]$/` Just to maintain symmetry ;)

Comment: @CinCout https://stackoverflow.com/a/4544642/2317490 ; not saying op will face it, i just get chills everytime i see the dot-star...

Comment: @Janie: I would have posted an answer but OP asked *Can I use something other than `|`?* so I am not sure if alternation based answer will be the right answer or not for OP.

Answer (score 2):

Since OP has specifically asked this part:

> Can I use something other than `|`?

Here is a regex solution that doesn't use alternation and uses [**negative lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to apply a condition that last character must not be `_` or `-`:

```
/^(?!.*[-_]$)[^-_].*/mg
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?!.*[-_]$)` is a negative lookahead that means fail the match is `-` or `_` are found just before end of line.
- `[^-_]` is a negated character class that means match any character that is not `-` or `_`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bIg4KP/1)

Having said that most simple and efficient solution would be what I wrote in my comment earlier i.e. using alternation:

```
/^[-_]|[-_]$/mg
```

Use this regex to check and fail your mismatches.

Comment: I voted it up. Could you please explain the first regex in your answer?

Comment: I have posted more details and also there is  very good link in my answer to read more about look arounds.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to alternate. Either match `[-_]` at the beginning (followed by other characters), *or* match any number of characters and then match `[-_]` at the end of the string:

```
^(?:[-_].*|.*[-_])$
```

https://regex101.com/r/e7ESHW/1

The group isn't *necessary*, but I think it makes the intent of the pattern clearer (a match must match the full length of the string). You can leave it out if you want:

```
^[-_].*|.*[-_]$
```

If you don't care at all about what characters get matched, and only want to see *if* the string starts with / ends with a dash or underscore, then you can leave out the `.*`s.

Comment: curious, why the group? and why the non-capturing?

Comment: @dandavis Arguably, the group could be unnecessary but why you think it shouldn't be a non-capturing one? I'm also more curious why the downvote! I see nothing wrong with the answer.

Comment: @dandavis I was thinking that (like OP's current pattern) a match should span the whole length of the string, so `^` and `$` on either sides of an alternated group makes sure that occurs. Capturing groups should only be used when needed - if they're not needed, a non-capturing group should be used instead, it's both less expensive and makes the intent of the pattern clearer.

Comment: yeah, but you don't need a group at all in the first place

Comment: @dandavis Not entirely sure how the pattern is being used, I was trying to fix OP's pattern while still matching the full strings. If OP is just using something like `.test`, then yeah, there's no need to check the other characters, but if he wants to extract certain matches, the whole length should be matched

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use something other than |?

Just in case you don't want to use regex, use [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

```js
let arr = ['sdq', 'lorem ipsum', 'abc_def', 'harry-_potter', 'fg_', '_asq', '_dqw-', '-asq-sq']

let tester = (str) => {
  return !(str.startsWith('-') || str.startsWith('_') || str.endsWith('-') || str.endsWith('_'))
}

arr.forEach(str => console.log(str, '--->', tester(str)))
```