# Regex to match strings when text starts with specific string

Tags: regex, obsidian

I am using [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md) with the [Obsidian_to_Anki](https://github.com/Pseudonium/Obsidian_to_Anki)-Plugin. I need Regex to match all first level headings of a page with a capturing group, but only when the page starts with `#match`. The plugin compiles the Regex with a multiline flag. The pages have this structure:

```markdown
#match

# Heading 1
Text of Heading 1
# Heading 2
Text of Heading 2
# Heading 3
Text of Heading 3
```

This shouldn't get matched:

```markdown
# Heading 1
Text of Heading 1
# Heading 2
Text of Heading 2
# Heading 3
Text of Heading 3
```

I came up with this Regex: `#match\s\s(# .*)`. But this way only `Heading 1` gets matched with capturing group 1, because there is no `#match` before `Heading 2`.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really. A regexp can only match a contiguous substring.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the expected match should look like, but does something like [`(?:\A#match|\G(?!\A))(?s:.)+?\K^(# .+)`](https://regex101.com/r/OKtVVv/1) do the trick? If that's the case, I'll write an answer explaining.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Seems to work! I just understood though, that I need a second capturing group matching text between two headings. The text may span over multiple lines. So: capturing group 1 should match the headings like your regex seems to do perfectly. Capturing group 2 should match everything below a first level Heading to the beginning of the next first level heading, `<!--ID` or `EOF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated

```
(?<=                        # Match something preceded by
  (?<![\s\S])               #          at the start of the file
  #match\n                  # '#match'
  [\s\S]*                   # and anything in between:
)                           # 
^(# .+)\n                   # A heading followed by
([\s\S]+?)                  # its corresponding content, which might be as long as possible,
(?=\n# |<!--ID|(?![\s\S]))  # until another heading, '<!--ID' or the end of file.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OKtVVv/3).

Since ECMAScript doesn't support `\A` and `\Z` (there's [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-buffer-boundaries) for adding them though), we'll have to make do by using negative lookarounds: `(?![\s\S])`/`(?<![\s\S])`. `[\s\S]` matches [any single character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4544636), so `(?![\s\S])` can only match at the position where no succeeding characters can be found: the end of string. The same explanation applies to `(?<![\s\S])`.

### Original answer

```
(?:\A#match|\G(?!\A))  # Match '#match' at the start of the file, or the end of the last match
\s*                    # followed by 0 or more whitespaces;
\K                     # we forfeit everything we just matched
^(# .+)\n              # then match and capture a heading, before continuing to the next line
([\s\S]+?)             # and capture the section's content,
(?=\n# |\Z)            # which must precedes either another heading or the end of file.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OKtVVv/2).

This makes use of the following metasequences:

- `\A`: The very start of the whole string
- `\G`: The end of the last match or `\A`
- `\G(?!\A)`: The end of the last match only
- `\K`: Forfeit everything matched by the expression on its left
- `\Z`: The end of string or the position before the last line terminator *iff* it is also the last character of the whole string.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems to work good with regex101 and sample text, got two problems though:
1) ID is also matched (ID is located at the end of `Text of Heading`). Tried to solve it like [this](https://regex101.com/r/itPOTE/1), but didn't work.
2) Doesn't seem to work at all with the Obsidian_to_Anki Plugin

Comment: @lukaskupfing 1) Yep, your fix seems good. 2) I saw the [tag:pcre] tag, so I assumed Obsidian uses PCRE. A quick search led me to [this forum post](https://forum.obsidian.md/t/regex-resources/3353), which points out that Obsidian uses ECMAScript flavor. Answer updated.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be using PCRE, sorry for the extra work! The updated regex101 link shows a pattern error

Comment: @lukaskupfing regex101 uses your browser's native implementation for ECMAscript flavor, so if you are using, say, [Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51568821), the regex won't work there. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKeqt.png)'s what I see.

Comment: oh wow, didn't know that! Works like a charm with obsidian! Thank you so much!