# Changing variable

Tags: php, mysql

This is my HAUNTED code.

```
ini_set("display_errors", true);
ini_set("html_errors", false); 
require "conn.php";
echo "debug 1";
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$stmt2->bind_param('s',$username);
//$username = $_POST["username"];
$username ="netsgets";
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->store_result(); 
if ($stmt2->num_rows == 0){ // username not taken
echo "debug 2.5";

die;
}else{
// prepare query
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param('s',$username);
$username = "netsgets";
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->store_result();  
// bind variables to result
$stmt->bind_result($id,$dbUser,$dbPassword,$Type1,$Type2,$Type3,$Type4,$Type5);
//fetch the first result row, this pumps the result values in the bound variables

if($stmt->fetch()){
    echo 'result is ' . $Type1, $Type2,$Type3,$Type4,$Type5;
}


//var_dump($query2);
echo "hi";

echo "debug 2";



echo "debug 2.7";

    if ($Type1 == "empty"){

        echo "debug 3";
        $sql11 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE UserData SET likedOne=? WHERE username=?");
        $sql11->bind_param('ss',$TUsername,$Username);
//      $TUsername = $_POST["TUsername"];
//      $Username = $_POST["username"];
        $TUsername = "test";
        $Username = "netsgets";
        $sql11->execute();



    } 
}
```

This is what it returns (echos).

```
Connected successfullydebug 1result is empty empty empty empty empty hidebug 2debug 2.7
```

As you can see, Variables Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4,Type5 all equal "empty".
For some reason, as you can see, the if statment doesn't think it is "empty" for it is not echoing "debug 3". What the..... (also no errors.)

Comment: You haven't declared $Type1, etc. anywhere.

Comment: $stmt->bind_result($id,$dbUser,$dbPassword,$Type1,$Type2,$Type3,$Type4,$Type5);

Comment: Is that not it?

Comment: plus if that is so, why can I print it's value?

Comment: You have to assign a value to those variables.

$Type1 = "Something"; //etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718986/checking-if-the-string-is-empty) SO question.

Comment: in the echoed text, you can see it equals "empty" already.

Comment: please help my problem

Comment: if I say Type1 = "empty" it works. How do I make $Type1 = the bind_result $Type1.

Comment: I would **never** use `SELECT *` in combination with `bind_result`. You should always be explicit regarding the columns selected and what order they appear in

Comment: @Difster your comments are not helping. I suggest you read the documentation for [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code...

```
echo 'result is ' . $Type1, $Type2,$Type3,$Type4,$Type5;
```

literally produces this output...

> result is empty empty empty empty empty

with spaces between each "empty", then obviously the `Type*` values in your database are all `"empty "` or `" empty"` or some other combination with leading / trailing whitespace.

You'll want to do the comparison with

```
trim($Type1) == 'empty'
```

---

Also, as mentioned in the comments, **never** use `SELECT *` in combination with `bind_result`. You should always be explicit regarding the columns selected and what order they appear in, eg

```
SELECT id, dbUser, dbPassword, Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, Type5 FROM ...
```

Comment: Sure, until you add or remove a column or your database decides to change the order