# Remove element that contain empty space and new line from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, trim

I am facing problem to removing white space and new line from array element.

I have tried below code

```
$explode_string = explode("\n", $GetGroupListOutput);    
$new_array = array();
foreach ($explode_string as $value) {                
    $value1 = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($value));        
    if(!empty($value1))
    {            
        $new_array[] = $value1;
    }
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

Output is like this

```
array(107147) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) ""
  [1]=>
  string(8) "
"
  [2]=>
  string(40) "Import Data"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "
"
  [4]=>
  string(6) ""
  [5]=>
  string(12) ""
  [6]=>
  string(13) ""
  [7]=>
  string(36) "All Masters"
```

My Output from api is like below.

```
  Import Data





    All Masters

     KRISHNA INTERIORS GSTR 3B






       -1
```

Above line show the output of my api. And output is not proper format.

Comment: Show me what string you are passing?

Comment: @Siddharthaesunuri string is coming other webhooks and it is not proper. That's why I am trying this.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: try use `if ($value1 !==  ''")` and not `empty` (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: I dont understand why string(10) is come for empty value???

Comment: What wrong here? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/798f6da592982c5cf1606b4e0925f5586ddf1d5a

Comment: Maybe you have encode problem? And check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/719002/6487675

Answer (score 0):

The simplest operation to match "white space and new line" would be `trim()`, which makes it an easy filter operation:

```php
$input = [
    "",
    "
",
    "Import Data",
    "
",
    " ",
    "  ",
    "   ",
    "All Masters",
];

$output = array_filter( $input, 'trim' );

var_dump( $output );
// array(2) { [2]=> string(11) "Import Data" [7]=> string(11) "All Masters" }
```