# Dynamic orWhere Clause

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a nested parameter grouping in my query where the value of one of my nested `where` is gotten from the form.

```
if($request->view != '') {
    $query->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', $request->view)
            ->orWhere('type', 2);
    })->get();
}
```

Right now I'm getting `Undefined variable: request`.
How do I get the value of `$request->view` in the function?

Comment: in this case you can use `->whereIn()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the `$request` variable into the anonymous function. Have a look at the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

In order to make your code work, you have to change it as follows:

```
if($request->view != '') {
    $query->where(function ($query) use($request) { // <-- without use, your 
      $query->where('type', $request->view)         //     anonymous function
            ->orWhere('type', 2);                   //     cannot access $request
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: `($request->view != '')`  could just be `(!$request->view)`

Comment: well not really... He's checking the `view` variable to be a **non empty string** so `(!$request->view)` will give a totally different result... Anyway I've simply copied and paste is code... to make an edit it should be `($request->view !== '')` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718986/checking-if-the-string-is-empty)

Answer (score 1):

```php
if($request->view != '') {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('type', $request->view)
            ->orWhere('type', 2);
    })->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it to scope with `use`

```php
if($request->view != '') {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('type', $request->view)
            ->orWhere('type', 2);
    })->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case not need use `orWhere()`. you can use `whereIn()`

```
if($request->view != '') {
    $query->whereIn('type', [$request->view, 2])
}
```